# Problems in find tools that does WCF migrations in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, migration

I'm try to find some works/applications/tools that does WCF migrations. I say this because I'm doing an investigation of similar applications that make migrations in .NET 6.

But the only two apps I find in this moment is [Visual Recode](https://visualrecode.com/) and this [Upgrade-assistant tool](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) (this last one idk if makes wcf migrations but when I read it converts .Net<6 apps to .Net6)

I try find more on the google but it gives links of "how to do migrations in c#" instead of "Tools/Applications that does migrations in c#" so its hard finding more.

Is there more apps/tools besides this 2 that does WCF Migrations? (Sry if this post is not a question one with specific code but I think maybe is relevant doing this for people who have the same problem as me and don't find more information about tools that does migrations)

Any help is always welcome

Comment: What do you mean by "migrations"?  WCF is a communications stack and migrations are usually associated with databases.  Are you trying to upgrade to .NET core and looking for a tool to get you there?

Comment: The migration term in this case is something like a upgrading. But yeah, i look for tools that upgrades for net core. Idk if the tag is wrong but if the tag is for db migrations i will remove the tag